# i want to connect via bluetooth classic in react native but give me error ,there are two problem

Tags: android, react-native, bluetooth

1. my app crashes when bluetooth is automatically connect to my headphone
2. when i make connction in bluetooth it not connected , it give me io exception , i tried all library , it give me error unable to connect, i take all permission in android manfest file , i can see it scan and show devices but not making connction.
   i tried to make connct to laptop

here is code

```
`import BluetoothSerial, { AndroidBluetoothDevice, device, pairDevice } from 'react-native-bluetooth-serial-next';
//important for  above package need to go nodemodules/react-native-bluetooth-serial-next/android/build.gradle ,then change min sdk to 23 and targe to 33
import RNBluetoothClassic, { BluetoothDevice, BluetoothEventType } from 'react-native-bluetooth-classic';





export const BluetoothScanner = ({navigation}:any) => {
  const [devices, setDevices] = useState<BluetoothDevice[]>([]);
  const [PairedDevices,set_PairedDevices]=useState<BluetoothDevice[]>([])
  const [isScanning, setIsScanning] = useState(false);
  const [BT_on,set_BT_on]=useState(false);
  const [message,setMessage]=useState('');
  const [selectedItem, setSelectedItem] = useState<BluetoothDevice|null>(null);
  const [isModalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false);
 
  const toggleModal = () => {
    setModalVisible(!isModalVisible);
  };
  // Initialize Bluetooth when the component mounts
 

  // Start scanning for devices
  const startScanning = async () => {
  
      try {
        console.log('h');
        setIsScanning(true);

        await RNBluetoothClassic.cancelDiscovery();
        const allDevices=await RNBluetoothClassic.startDiscovery();
        await RNBluetoothClassic.cancelDiscovery()
        setIsScanning(false);
        //put seached device and stored device in set to get unique array
        setDevices(allDevices);
         
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching Bluetooth devices:', error);
      }
    };

 

  const connect=async (device:BluetoothDevice)=>{
    try{
      const connectdevice=await device.isConnected();
      if(!connectdevice){
          if(!PairedDevices.includes(device)){
              await RNBluetoothClassic.pairDevice(device.address);
            }
            if(device.bonded){
            
            const connected=await RNBluetoothClassic.connectToDevice(device.id);
            
            if(connected){
              console.log(connected);
              
              //check if device is same i want 
              toggleModal();//open Modal screen 
              //get the character of battery, other detail and set to usestate
              //then usestate will elemt will set in Modal screen
              AsyncStorage.setItem('device_id',device.id).then(()=>setMessage('Paired successfully'));//store in async storage
              navigation.navigate('Home',{bt:true,});
            }
        
        
        
          }
        }
      setSelectedItem(null);
    }
        catch(err){       
          setSelectedItem(null);
          console.error('Error pairing with device:', err);
    };
  } `
```

i tried all libray like react native bluettoh serial, rnbluettoh classic,react native ble plx, all , i treid to connct to headphoned bia bleplx library , i see all are giving me same error 'not conncted'

Comment: If your phone is automatically opening a connection to the other device using another profile (such as your headphones using A2DP) then attempting to open an RFCOMM socket to the same device will fail.  You need to ensure that your peripheral doesn't already have a connection.